# Classification of certain standardly stratified algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $A$ be a local algebra and $M$ an indecomposable $A$-modules. When is the algebra $B:=End_A(A \oplus M)$ standardly stratified?
In particular, is $End_A(A \oplus S)$ standardly stratified for a simple module $S$?
As a special case of the main theorem 2.4. in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869304004983,
this is for example the case when $A$ is commutative selfinjective and $M$ is a module with simple socle and top. (if I understand that main theorem correctly in this special case)
edit: Answer for a simple modules is positive:
http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0021869305003200/1-s2.0-S0021869305003200-main.pdf?_tid=d687d170-bd78-11e6-9185-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1481223917_6f2f9e4b4d84a0163f57df4d922bbf51